# Is there a resource with all the iOS settings localization strings?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization

My app needs some localized strings which are identical to the ones in the Settings app. I wasn't lucky with Google but maybe someone knows a resource which attempted to put the strings of all languages together for copy & paste?

Talking about strings such as "International" and "General" for Settings. Why re-invent the wheel when Apple did the hard work for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Preparing Your Nib Files for Localization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002138-BBCBFFDF)?

Comment: Nah, I'm looking for the translation strings of all strings in the standard Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is really bad about providing translations. Microsoft has a full glossary you can look up and search (https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx), which can be helpful generally speaking. For iOS, however, you want to use the same translations Apple uses for your app. For instance, "Settings" in Spanish is always "Ajustes" -- even though many other OSes use "Configuraciones".

I have never found an Apple glossary, so we finally put one together ourselves. You can find it here: http://www.ibabbleon.com/glossary